# How to effectively deal with a Python dictionary with dynamic keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, opendata

How to effectively deal with a Python dictionary with dynamic keys?

I work with open data from the Netherlands. There is a dictionary for each area / year. The dictionary keys are different for each year. How can I write effective code dealing with this?

I have two working constructs, as in the examples below: But both require effort for each key and there are 108 keys in the open data so I really hope Python offers a better solution that I am not yet aware of!

FYI about the open data:
Each year is a list with 16194 dictionaries. One dictionary per neighbourhood in NL. Each dictionary has 108 items (key, value pairs):

```
>>> import cbsodata
>>> table = '83487NED'
>>> data = cbsodata.get_data(table, dir=None, typed=False)
Retrieving data from table '83487NED'
Done!
>>> len(data)
16194
>>> data[0]
{'Gehuwd_14': 1565, 'MateVanStedelijkheid_105': 5, 'Bevolkingsdichtheid_33':   1350, 'Gemeentenaam_1': 'Aa en Hunze                             ', ... etc     
>>> len(data[0])
108
```

A key may be 'Code_3' in one year and 'Code_4' in the next year...

Example data used for example solutions:

```
data2016 = [{'Code_3': 'BU01931000', 'ZipCode_106': '2251MT', 'City_12': 'Amsterdam', 'Number_of_people_5': '24000'},
                {'Code_3': 'BU02221000', 'ZipCode_106': '2851MT', 'City_12': 'London', 'Number_of_people_5': '88000'},
                {'Code_3': 'BU04444000', 'ZipCode_106': '2351MT', 'City_12': 'Paris', 'Number_of_people_5': '133000'}]
data2015 = [{'Code_4': 'BU01931000', 'ZipCode_106': '2251MT', 'City_12': 'Amsterdam', 'Number_of_people_6': '22000'},
                {'Code_4': 'BU02221000', 'ZipCode_106': '2851MT', 'City_12': 'London', 'Number_of_people_6': '86000'},
                {'Code_4': 'BU04444000', 'ZipCode_106': '2351MT', 'City_12': 'Paris', 'Number_of_people_6': '131000'}]
data2014 = [{'Code_8': 'BU01931000', 'ZipCode_109': '2251MT', 'City_12': 'Amsterdam', 'Number_of_people_14': '18000'},
                {'Code_8': 'BU02221000', 'ZipCode_109': '2851MT', 'City_12': 'London', 'Number_of_people_14': '76000'},
                {'Code_8': 'BU04444000', 'ZipCode_109': '2351MT', 'City_12': 'Paris', 'Number_of_people_14': '129000'}]
data2013 = [{'Code_8': 'BU01931000', 'ZipCode_109': '2251MT', 'City_12': 'Amsterdam', 'Number_of_people_14': '14000'},
                {'Code_8': 'BU02221000', 'ZipCode_109': '2851MT', 'City_12': 'London', 'Number_of_people_14': '74000'}] # data for Paris 'BU04444000' missing in 2013
tables = {2013: data2013, 2014: data2014, 2015: data2015, 2016: data2016}
years = [2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]
current_year = 2016
```

Example solution 1, mapping of keys:

```
def CBSkey(key, year):
    if key == 'key_code':
        if year == 2013:
            return('Code_8')
        elif year == 2014:
            return('Code_8')
        elif year == 2015:
            return('Code_4')
        elif year == 2016:
            return('Code_3')
    elif key == 'key_people':
        if year == 2013:
            return('Number_of_people_14')
        elif year == 2014:
            return('Number_of_people_14')
        elif year == 2015:
            return('Number_of_people_6')
        elif year == 2016:
            return('Number_of_people_5')

for record_now in tables[current_year]:
    code = record_now['Code_3']
    city = record_now['City_12']
    people = {}
    for year in years:
        code_year = CBSkey('key_code', year)
        people_year = CBSkey('key_people', year)
        for record in tables[year]:
            if record[code_year] == code:
                people[year] = (record[people_year])

    print(people)
```

Output for all 3 example solutions:

```
{2016: '24000', 2013: '14000', 2014: '18000', 2015: '22000'}
{2016: '88000', 2013: '74000', 2014: '76000', 2015: '86000'}
{2016: '133000', 2014: '129000', 2015: '131000'}
```

Example 2, select the right dictionary based on the item and then loop through all other keys to find the additional data:

```
for record_now in tables[current_year]:
    city = record_now['City_12']
    code = record_now['Code_3']
    print('Code: ', code)
    people = {}
    for year in years:
        for record in tables[year]:
            for v in record.values():
                if v == code:
                    for k in record.keys():
                        key_type = CBSkey(k)
                        if key_type == 'People_type':
                            people[year] = (record[k])
    print(people)
```

Hoping for some bright 'Pythonic' ideas, many thanks in advance!

Comment: This is quite long and detailed. Please read about [minimal working examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks Tom. I have removed about 40%!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this data set correctly, each year’s data is a list of
many dicts; all of the dicts for a given year use the same keys; the
keys vary from year to year, but the general data available is the same.
So you need a way to efficiently retrieve the same data from multiple
years.

First, I would put all of the years into one big dict, instead of using
the indirect mapping scheme you have:

```
data = {}
data[2016] = [{'Code_3': 'BU01931000'}] # etc.
data[2015] = [{'Code_4': 'BU01931000'}] # etc.
```

So `tables` and all the individual `datayyyy` go away, `tables[year]`
becomes `data[year]`, and `years` becomes `data.keys()`.

Then, I would work out a mapping from year to keys.

```
"""ytok structure

ytok maps years to dicts of keys. ytok[2016] would be:
{'code': 'Code_3', 'zip': 'ZipCode_106', 'city': 'City_12',
 'people': 'Number_of_people_5'}
"""
```

Here is one way to construct `ytok`, showing intermediate results to
make the process clear:

```
ytok = {}

for year in data.keys():
    sample = data[year][0]
    outputs = list(sorted(sample.keys()))
    # Will be in this order: city, code, people, zip
    inputs = 'city code people zip'.split()
    pairs = list(zip(inputs, outputs))
    print(pairs)
    yeardict = dict(pairs)
    print(yeardict)
    ytok[year] = yeardict

print(ytok)
```

Here is a more streamlined way:

```
inputs = 'city code people zip'.split()
for year in data.keys():
    outputs = sorted(data[year][0].keys())
    ytok[year] = dict(zip(inputs, outputs))

print(ytok)
```

Then use `ytok` like so:

```
wanted_code = 'BU02221000'
people = {}
for year in data.keys():
    codekey = ytok[year]['code']
    peoplekey = ytok[year]['people']
    for record in data[year]:
        if record[codekey] == wanted_code:
            people[year] = record[peoplekey]
            break

print(people)
```

Note the use of `break` once the correct record has been found. There’s
no point in continuing to search a year once we’ve found what we want,
so we break out of the inner `for record` loop.

Comment: Thanks for this nice solution!

Comment: Glad it was useful :)